# Entire columns as parameters to Redshift SP

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm using AWS Redshift where I have a temporary table called `temp` with `latitude` and `longitude` columns.

I want to use `latitude` and `longitude` to perform a calculation for every row of the table. This calculation holds business logic, which is programmed in a stored procedure and is already working.

The SP is called `sp_calculation()` under `my_schema`, it takes two input parameters (`latitude` and `longitude`) and returns a single number called `g_key`

Example: if I run `CALL my_schema.sp_calculation(latitude, longitude)` I get a single number, `g_key`, as a result.

---

The problem I have is that the stored procedure takes single values as input parameters, not entire columns.

I would like to pass the entire columns `latitude` and `longitude` to the SP or loop across them and, if possible, insert the resulting value `g_key` into `temp` (for which I will have to alter the table in order to have the column `g_key`, I know, but I can do that in a previous step of my workflow)

Expected results (numbers are illustrative only):

`SELECT * FROM temp LIMIT 2;`

| latitude | longitude | g_key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 28 | 32 | 1000 |
| 30 | 32 | 990 |

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like this would be better as a user-defined function which you can run per-row.